# Angular post request return ERROR in console

Tags: node.js, json, angular, post

So i am sending a POST request to a nodeJS app, my request in Angular looks like this:

```
newWord = '';
  keyword = '';

  onClick() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http
      .post('http://localhost:3000/search',{
        keyword: this.keyword,
        responseType: 'text',
        headers: headers,
      })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.newWord = data as string;
      })
  }
```

My Node app post response is set like this:

```
app.post("/search", (req, res) => {
  search(req.body.keyword).then((ids) => {
    
    console.log(ids[0].text);
    res.send(ids[0].text);
  });
  
});
```

My problem is that when opening the console in the localhost i get this error

[image]

Comment: Does that mean that this.newWord = data the data is an observable object even though i set response = 'text' @Drenai

Comment: That doesnt help at all tho...

Comment: Url, body, options. Http.post correct order.

Comment: @MikeOne Well the post request goes correctly the Node app recieves the request and i perform a search with the twitter api but when i try to return the request everythings goes wrong. I tried putting in the body the this.keyword (input field value) but the nodeJS app couldnt get it, it just got undefined so i set the keyword: this.keyword in options and it worked.

Comment: now when i try to input the value into a field i get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP POST request need to change (as @Drenai and @MikeOne stated in the comments):

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/search',
               {keyword: this.keyword},
               {responseType: 'text',
                headers: headers,
               })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.newWord = data as string;
      })
```

Comment: Oh now i understand thanks a lot marking this as the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I can see you just sent a response as a text so on the client-side try parse response body giving issue.

so send a response in JSON format in the node itself I hope it helps.

```
app.post("/search", (req, res) => {
  search(req.body.keyword).then((ids) => {
    
    console.log(ids[0].text);
    **res.send({response:ids[0].text});**
  });



this.http
      .post('http://localhost:3000/search',{
        keyword: this.keyword,
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'text',
      })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data['reponse']);
        this.newWord = data['response'];
      })
```